# Is it possible to have record type pop up before account creation on a visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, record-type, form

The wording of the question may be a little weird, but I am designing a search system that will search additional databases to add companies from there to Salesforce. If the company is not found in any of the DBs, the page is rerendered to a form that allow's a user to create the account from scratch, which looks like this so far.
[image]

However, there are many record types in the org I am working in and would like to know if it is possible to have the record type splash screen pop up before the previously mentioned account creation form. Based on the record type selected, the form would display the appropriate fields to be filled out. The record type splash screen I am refering to looks like this.
[image]

If anyone has any ideas/suggestions as to how I may go about this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems you're going to face is that every user is assigned a default record type in their user profile, so the RecordType will automatically default to what's in their profile. You could potentially overwrite this in your controller using a select option list.

Aside from that, you're going to need to create a modal using Javascript that pops up based on some action, like when the page re-renders in order to display the form. You'd use logic to call 'some function' that would execute 'init()' when 'displayform="true"' on the visualforce page. That's the best example of the pseudo-logic for the code I can provide you without writing it for you. I'm confident you'll find plenty of examples of this in code in this form or around the web.